# Tacx Flux 2 - How do you mount a Axle Equipped Bike on it?

Tags: trainer, through-axle

I’ve recently bought the Liv Avail Advanced 2 Pro Axs and wanted to mount it on my trainer, a Tacx Flux 2, which also seems to have different types of axles.
I can not seem to find the measurements on Liv’s website to order the correct one from Tacx's selection.

I’ve already saw a bunch of videos but I cannot understand if I have to buy a 12mm thru axle adapter, or if I can use the one that comes with the trainer, or if I can use the original one from the bike.

I used to have a quick release mount and I’m very confused right now. What is the correct way to mount my thru-axle equipped bike on this trainer?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time with a thru-axle bike on a wheel-off trainer, you use the axle you have. When set up properly, the trainer has exactly the dimensions of the hub.

The trainer will need to be set up with the thru-axle endcaps for 142x12. Typically trainers come with these in the box. The manual has instructions (though admittedly not great ones) for installing them. It appears you need an 8mm allen wrench and 17mm open wrench to do so.

[image]
[image]